# how to send data from java class to adapter class with the help of constructor android?

Tags: android

I'm really new in Android and java. I have this problem, I have an Activity (MainActivity) and adapter class.

The problem is with constructor, data is not sending from java class to adapter class.

MainActivity:

```
     public searchActivity(string journey)
      {
       this.journey=journey;
     }
```

Adpterclass:

```
  SearchActivity obj=new SearchActivity(journey)
```

Comment: give the code structure you are working on.

Comment: when i m try to print the journey, it shows null. but journey have some data in class file